# Linux + XPS15 9550 + Thunderbolt 3 docking station (USB and Ethernet not working)

Tags: 16.04, thunderbolt

I have a xps 15 9550 running dual boot system (win 10 and linux) and a docking station brought from Amazon (http://a.co/1oTsVhj). I have noticed that the docking station works perfectly on win 10, but when I use Linux, the only port would work is the display port, and none of other ports would work. My Linux is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the Kernel is 4.15.3. I don't what is going on and how to make it work.

Thanks,

Comment: bought*  not brought. sorry

Answer (score 6):

I also have a dual boot system of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 and I had the same problem. My laptop is a HP ZBook 17 G4 with a HP Zbook Thunderbolt 3 Dock. I found the following solution:

1. Go to your BIOS setup
2. Go to the Advanced tab then Boot settings, disable the FastBoot (this allows for the use of the thunderbolt technology pre-boot)
3. Go to the Advanced tab then Port settings:
4. Disable the "Require BIOS PW (password) for TBT
   (thunderbolt)" or something similar (This shows/allows the option
   for no security on thunderbolt tech, see next step)
5. Change the Thunderbolt security configuration (a dropdown for me) to "PCIe & USB" or the option with no security.
6. Save and reboot, my Ubuntu
   OS immediately started using the 2 displays and the USB Mouse and
   keyboard that were connected to the HP Thunderbolt 3 Dock

Hope this helps more people, as for now there are still no Linux drivers to use this Thunderbolt technology securely

Comment: Thanks so much. Also worked with my ZBook G5 and dock

Comment: Did this also give you access to the dock ethernet?

Comment: This fixed almost everything for my Belkin dock with my Lenovo - USB, Ethernet, even the monitor connection works better. It still refuses to charge, for some reason.

Comment: Disabling fastboot was the only option I needed, and then my ethernet "enp55s0u2u4" device showed up. Thanks